# Is there an R function for finding RMSEs and RMSEu?

Tags: r

Currently, I am trying to find the RMSE systematic (RMSEs) and RMSE unsystematic (RMSEu) for a fitted model and an actual observation in R.

To arrive at the RMSE, I used the following:

```
sqrt( mean( (df$fitted - df$actual)^2 , na.rm = TRUE ) )
```

However, I am not sure how I can calculate RMSEu and RMSEs from this using R. Are there any functions/packages I can use to calculate these?

Thanks a lot!

Edit:

[Here's the definition of RMSEu and RMSEs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc4AO.png)

Comment: It would be useful to provide the definitions of RMSEs and RMSEu

Comment: Hi, here's the definition: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc4AO.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the relevant library for this! :-)
Thanks to those who have helped.
For those still seeking a library for RMSEs and RMSEu, check out:
https://rdrr.io/github/SticsRPacks/CroPlotR/man/predictor_assessment.html

Answer (score 0):

Adrian, There is an `RMSE` function in the `caret` package

```
# Load library
library(caret)

# Check Root Mean Squared Error
RMSE(pred = df$fitted, obs = df$actual)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several RMSE functions in R packages, but I am not aware of one that has systematic and unsystematic RMSE. Might write our own function, sth. like
`sqrt(1/N * sum((modeled - observed)^2))`
and likewise. Here, vectorisation comes in handy, i.e. the `(differences)^2` term will yield a vector of the squares of the differences, that can be summed up.